# How to match end of string in lookahead?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Why this do not match and how to make it work?

```
Regex.Match("qwe", ".*?(?=([ $]))");
```

I should match everything to first space or to the end of line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your specific problem is that you need to use an alternation, not a character class, because inside a character class the $ symbol literally means "match a dollar symbol", and does not have its special meaning end-of-line in that context.

```
( |$)
```

It seems however that your example is a bit strange. It would be simpler to match any character except space, then you wouldn't need a lookahead at all.

Comment: No it's not. Because of ? it's not greedy

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
Regex.Match("qwe", "^([^ ]*)");
```